# If an unloaded transformer doesn't draw current, how can it cause induction?

Tags: electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

An ideal transformer whose secondary coil is not connected to a load apparently does not draw any current from its driving voltage source. However, if this is really the case, and no current is running through the primary coil, then there is no self induction that prevents the current from flowing in the first place... so it should flow. But if it flows, then, there is self induction, so no current flows. This seems like a complete paradox: If current flows, it doesn't flow, but if it doesn't flow, it flows! What is the resolution to this?

Answer (score 10):

The transformer does draw a current. But because the unloaded primary coil is a reasonable inductor, the current is almost 90 degrees out of phase with the voltage, so that the total power is low.

Comment: An ideal transformer with zero resistance wires and perfect (linear) magnetic core would be a perfect inductor where the ac current and voltage would be out of phase exactly $90^°$.  Thus no average power would flow into the primary coil.